# get_or_create in Peewee

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

The paragraph titled [Get or create](http://peewee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#create-or-get) on the peewee documentation says:

> While peewee has a `get_or_create()` method, this should really not be
>   used outside of tests as it is vulnerable to a race condition. The
>   proper way to perform a *get* or *create* with peewee is to rely on the
>   database to enforce a constraint.

And then it goes on with an example that only shows the create part, not the get part.

What is the best way to perform a get or create with peewee?

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing out the docs issue. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you are doing inside a transaction is atomic.

So as long as you are calling `get_or_create()` inside a transaction, that paragraph is wrong.